# Mutable borrow to object inside Mutex - how to refactor?

Tags: rust, refactoring, mutex, borrowing

I have the following pattern in many of my functions:

```
use std::sync::{Arc, Mutex};

struct State { 
    value: i32
}

fn foo(data: Arc<Mutex<State>>) {
    let state = &mut data.lock().expect("Could not lock mutex");
    // mutate `state`
}
```

`&mut *data.lock().expect("Could not lock mutex")` is repeated over and over, so I would like to refactor it to a function, in order to write something like

```
let state = get_state(data);
```

I've tried the following:

```
fn get_state(data: &Arc<Mutex<State>>) -> &mut State {
    &mut data.lock().expect("Could not lock mutex")
}
```

Which fails to compile with:

> ERROR: cannot return value referencing temporary value

This makes me believe that `data.state.lock().expect("...")` returns by value. However, I can see the state being mutated through multiple `foo` calls [**on this playground**](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=7d968a7f324ffeb11d4c9e70187c08f2).

**What is going on here? Why does my seemingly simple refactor fail to compile?**

---

EDIT:

I would expect the following to work as well:

```
fn get_state<'a>(data: &'a Arc<Mutex<State>>) -> &'a mut State {
    let state: &'a mut State = &mut data.lock().expect("Could not lock mutex");
    state
}
```

But it fails with:

```
   |
12 | fn get_state<'a>(data: &'a Arc<Mutex<State>>) -> &'a mut State {
   |              -- lifetime `'a` defined here
13 |     let state: &'a mut State = &mut data.lock().expect("Could not lock mutex");
   |                -------------        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ creates a temporary which is freed while still in use
   |                |
   |                type annotation requires that borrow lasts for `'a`
14 |     state
15 | }
   | - temporary value is freed at the end of this statement
```

**Why doesn't the lifetime of whatever is returned from `lock` match the one of the `data` parameter?**

Comment: `lock()` returns a `MutexGuard` and not the value itself. You can access the value stored inside because it implements `Deref` and `DerefMut`, but still you are referencing the mutex guard. When the mutex guard goes out of scope, your reference will point to freed memory, so rust is preventing that from happening. (Remember that the mutex lock will be released once the mutex guard goes out of scope!!!) PS: Instead of hiding the `.expect()` in another method you should properly handle the error case

Comment: @SvetlinZarev: that makes sense. Let's say I don't use `expect`, and I do handle the error, but the error handling is the same in every function. Again, how do I avoid the repetition in that case? The only way I can think of is a higher-order function - is that idiomatic?

Comment: I really cannot say what is idiomatic, but my observation is that common repetitive tasks are usually handled by macros.

Comment: The refactoring would be valid if you change the result type from `&mut State` to `MutexGuard<State>`. @Svetlin: I think this is what you wanted to express right?

Comment: I meant that one cannot bypass the `MutexGuard`.  If OP returns MutexGuard -> then that should work.

Comment: @SvetlinZarev: I am OK with returning `MutexGuard`, feel free to add that as an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `lock()` method returns `MutexGuard` instead of a direct reference to the guarded object. You are able to work with object reference, because `MutexGuard` implements `Deref` and `DerefMut`, but you still need the mutex-guard to be in scope, because when it goes out of scope the mutex lock will be released. Also the lifetime of the reference to the inner object is bound to the lifetime of the mutex guard, so the compiler will not allow you to use the reference to the inner object without the mutex guard.

You can extract your common logic in a macro or a method, but it should return MutexGuard instead of a reference to the inner object.

Answer (score 7):

One way to abstract over locking and unlocking a mutex is for the API to accept a closure and pass the unlocked reference to it.

```
fn with_state<R>(data: Arc<Mutex<State>>, f: impl FnOnce(&mut State) -> R) -> R {
    let state = &mut data.lock().expect("Could not lock mutex");
    f(state)
}
```

Given `with_state`, you can write `foo` as follows:

```
fn foo(data: Arc<Mutex<State>>) {
    with_state(data, |state| state.value += 1)
}
```

This is similar to the way crates like `crossbeam` guarantee that scoped threads always join. It is stricter than returning a `MutexGuard` because when you call `with_state`, the guard is guaranteed to be dropped after the closure returns. On the other hand, returning a `MutexGuard` is more general because you can write `with_state` in terms of a function that returns a guard, but you can't go the other way around (use `with_state` to write a function that returns a guard).